# JavaFX SplitMenuButton setting the position of the arrow

Tags: java, button, javafx

A normal SplitMenuButton looks like this:
[Standard SplitMenuButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD5W4.png)

I would like to change the location of the arrow in a JavaFX SplitMenuButton but cannot work out if there is even a configuration that will give me something like this:
[SplitMenuButton with arrow on bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUuio.png)

Is this possible or will I need to create a bespoke version of split menu button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the JavaFX SplitMenuButton I could not find any way to easily reproduce what I need (menu arrow on side other than default right). I created a button class that allows the arrow button to be placed on any side of the main button( or even hidden). The class is not polished but does the job. The great thing about this sample class is that the arrow side can be changed dynamically.

Code for class:

```
public class MyButton extends Group {

private ButtonBase label;
private ButtonBase arrowButton;
protected ContextMenu popup;
private ObjectProperty<SplitMode> splitMode;
private DoubleProperty sizeBinding;
private DoubleProperty layoutBinding;
private double oldSizeValue;
private double oldLayoutValue;
private PseudoClass layoutClass;

//
private static PseudoClass TOP_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("top");
private static PseudoClass BOTTOM_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("bottom");
private static PseudoClass LEFT_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("left");
private static PseudoClass RIGHT_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("right");
private static PseudoClass HIDDEN_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("hidden");

public static enum SplitMode {
    SPLIT_TOP, // put arrow buton on top
    SPLIT_RIGHT, // put arrow button on right
    SPLIT_BOTTOM, // bottom
    SPLIT_LEFT, // left
    HIDDEN  // hides the arrow button regardless of visibility
}

private void changeToPseudoClass(PseudoClass newClass) {
    pseudoClassStateChanged(layoutClass, false);
    pseudoClassStateChanged(newClass, true);
    layoutClass = newClass;
}

private void bindHidden() {

    if (sizeBinding != null) {
        sizeBinding.unbind();
        sizeBinding.set(oldSizeValue);
    }
    if (layoutBinding != null) {
        layoutBinding.unbind();
        layoutBinding.set(oldLayoutValue);
    }
    arrowButton.setVisible(false);
    changeToPseudoClass(HIDDEN_PSEUDO_CLASS);
}

private void bindSizeAndLayout(DoubleProperty sizeFrom, ReadOnlyDoubleProperty sizeTo,
        DoubleProperty layoutFrom, ReadOnlyDoubleProperty layoutTo,
        PseudoClass newPseudoClass) {

    if (sizeBinding != null) {
        sizeBinding.unbind();
        sizeBinding.set(oldSizeValue);
    }
    if (layoutBinding != null) {
        layoutBinding.unbind();
        layoutBinding.set(oldLayoutValue);
    }
    oldSizeValue = sizeFrom.get();
    sizeBinding = sizeFrom;
    oldLayoutValue = layoutFrom.get();
    layoutBinding = layoutFrom;
    sizeFrom.bind(sizeTo);
    layoutFrom.bind(layoutTo);
    changeToPseudoClass(newPseudoClass);
    arrowButton.setVisible(true);
}

public void setSplitMode(SplitMode mode) {
    if (splitMode == null) {
        splitMode = new SimpleObjectProperty();
    }
    if (splitMode.get() == mode) {
        return;
    } // no changes needed   
    splitMode.set(mode);

    // set up new bindings
    switch (mode) {
        case SPLIT_BOTTOM:
            // bind arrowbutton width to label width
            // bind arrowbutton starting position to bottom of label
            bindSizeAndLayout(arrowButton.prefWidthProperty(), label.widthProperty(),
                    arrowButton.layoutYProperty(), label.heightProperty(),
                    BOTTOM_PSEUDO_CLASS);
            break;
        case SPLIT_RIGHT:
            // bind arrowbutton height to label height
            bindSizeAndLayout(arrowButton.prefHeightProperty(), label.heightProperty(),
                    arrowButton.layoutXProperty(), label.widthProperty(),
                    RIGHT_PSEUDO_CLASS);
            break;
        case SPLIT_LEFT:
            // bind arrowbutton height to label height
            bindSizeAndLayout(arrowButton.prefHeightProperty(), label.heightProperty(),
                    label.layoutXProperty(), arrowButton.widthProperty(),
                    LEFT_PSEUDO_CLASS);
            break;
        case SPLIT_TOP:
            // bind arrowbutton width to label height
            bindSizeAndLayout(arrowButton.prefWidthProperty(), label.widthProperty(),
                    label.layoutYProperty(), arrowButton.heightProperty(),
                    TOP_PSEUDO_CLASS);
            break;
        case HIDDEN:
            // unbind all and hide button
            bindHidden();
            break;
    }

}

public SplitMode getSplitMode() {
    return (splitMode == null) ? SplitMode.HIDDEN : splitMode.get();
}

public ObjectProperty splitModeProperty() {
    return splitMode;
}

public ButtonBase getButton() {
    return label;
}

public ButtonBase getArrowButton() {
    return arrowButton;
}

// Test suite
public MyButton() {
    this("");
}

public MyButton(String text) {
    this(text, SplitMode.SPLIT_RIGHT);
}

@SuppressWarnings("OverridableMethodCallInConstructor")
public MyButton(String text, SplitMode mode) {
    label = new Button(text);
    label.getStyleClass().setAll("label");
    arrowButton = new Button();
    // bind the managed property to visibility.
    // we dont want to manage an invisible button.
    arrowButton.managedProperty().bind(arrowButton.visibleProperty());
    arrowButton.getStyleClass().setAll("arrow-button");
    getStyleClass().setAll("split-menu-button");
    getChildren().clear();
    getChildren().addAll(label, arrowButton);
    setSplitMode(mode);

}

}// end of class
```

MyButton class creates additional pseudo classes to enable special formatting for each side.

Sample css:

```css
.split-menu-button > .label {
    -fx-background-color:  -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1, 2 1 2 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 0 0 5, 4 0 0 4, 3 0 0 3;
    -fx-padding: 0.166667em 0.667em 0.25em 0.833333em; /* 2 8 3 10 */
    /* -fx-graphic:url("./icon_32.png"); */
    -fx-content-display: top;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
.split-menu-button:top > .label {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1, 2 1 2 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 5 5, 0 0 4 4, 0 0 3 3;
}
.split-menu-button:right > .label {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1, 2 1 2 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 0 0 5, 4 0 0 4, 3 0 0 3;
}
.split-menu-button:bottom > .label {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1, 2 1 2 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
}
.split-menu-button:left > .label {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1, 2 1 2 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 5 5 0, 0 4 4 0, 0 3 3 0;
}
.split-menu-button:hidden > .label {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1, 2 1 2 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5, 4 4 4 4, 3 3 3 3;
}
.split-menu-button > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 5 5 0, 0 4 4 0, 0 3 3 0;
    -fx-padding: 0; /* 0.5em 0.667em 0.5em 0.667em; /* 6 8 6 8 */
    -fx-graphic:url("./arrow.png");
    -fx-alignment:center;
}
.split-menu-button:top > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
}
.split-menu-button:right > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 5 5 0, 0 4 4 0, 0 3 3 0;
}
.split-menu-button:bottom > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 5 5, 0 0 4 4, 0 0 3 3;
}
.split-menu-button:left > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 0 0 5, 4 0 0 4, 3 0 0 3;
}
```

Sample Application to test button.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import MyButton.SplitMode;

public class SimpleTest
    extends Application {

    Stage primaryStage;
    protected ContextMenu popup;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage = stage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("SimpleTest.");

        Label label = new Label();
        Button rotate = new Button("Rotate");
        MyButton b = new MyButton("My Test", SplitMode.SPLIT_TOP);
        label.setText(b.getSplitMode().toString());
        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        sp.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        sp.getStylesheets().add("test.css");

        rotate.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
            switch(b.getSplitMode()){
                case SPLIT_TOP:
                    b.setSplitMode(SplitMode.SPLIT_RIGHT);
                    break;
                case SPLIT_RIGHT:
                    b.setSplitMode(SplitMode.SPLIT_BOTTOM);
                    break;
                case SPLIT_BOTTOM:
                    b.setSplitMode(SplitMode.SPLIT_LEFT);
                    break;
                case SPLIT_LEFT:
                    b.setSplitMode(SplitMode.HIDDEN);
                    break;
                case HIDDEN:
                    b.setSplitMode(SplitMode.SPLIT_TOP);
                    break;
            }
            label.setText(b.getSplitMode().toString());
        });
        StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        StackPane.setAlignment(rotate, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        sp.getChildren().addAll(b, label, rotate);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sp));
        primaryStage.toFront();
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
   }
```

Comment: hi it seems that your solution isn't compled the popup is never used?